# What is the opposite of the verb obfuscate?

Tags: antonyms

The opposite for veil is unveil but what is the opposite for obfuscate? Is it unobfuscate?

Comment: google [ obfuscate antonym ] .

Comment: @MetaEd, just tried it; it leads back here...

Comment: In the first page of the search results: ***Simplify, streamline; disentangle, straighten (out), undo (M-W). To deliberately make less confusing: explain, simplify (Wiktionary).*** Plus links to other sources of antonyms for the word.

Comment: @MetaEd: I wasn't searching for a bunch of similar words but the exact opposite.

Comment: The reason you are not getting that kind of answer is that it's not what you asked. If you are wanting to know which prefix is most commonly used to reverse the meaning of *obfuscate*, try editing the question to say that. Cheers, Edward

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If we're talking about obfuscated computer code then the antonym used when translating it back to normal is *deobfuscate*.

None of the "general references" appear to include that specialised use.

Answer (score 11):

I was going to suggest *clarify*, but I've learned that *obfuscate* comes from the Latin *[obfuscatus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=obfuscate&searchmode=none)* meaning *to darken*, I'm going to suggest *[illuminate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illuminate)*:

> : to make clear : elucidate

**EDIT:**  In light of Jay's comment (pun intended), I bring you ***[clarify](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clarify)***:

> 2: to free of confusion *needs time to clarify his thoughts*
>
> 3: to make understandable *clarify a subject*

Comment: I think your original suggestion of "clarify" is better. Regardless of Latin origins, in English the word does not mean to turn off the lights in the literal sense. True, "illuminate" can also be used to mean "clarify" in a metaphorical sense. But it's less clear ... or should I say more obfuscated?